# Ajax and jQuery custom form submission in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm not a tech completely, and I'm trying to build my custom theme for WordPress.
So, I came to a point that I need to implement a custom JS script to send the form data. As far as I understand, it's going to be a PHP file, but now I'm concentrated on front-end. This is AJAX + jQuery validation. 
I don't want my form to refresh the page after it sends the data, just a simple message telling that everything went successful.

Can anyone have a look at the code I wrote and tell me what's wrong with it? It took me just two days..

PS - the file, that stores that code is embedded into WP theme properly, with a jQuery as a dependancy. I wonder, do I have to do anything to implement AJAX, or it comes with jQuery?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpdRpE

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="form__item form__item_no-margin">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="What's your name?*" class="firstname" required>
    <p class="error-message">Sorry, but this field can't be empty.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form__item">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="What's your email address?*" class="email" required>
    <p class="error-message">Oopps, I haven't seen emails like that.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form__item">
    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Want to leave any message?*" class="textarea" required></textarea>
    <p class="error-message">Nothing to say at all? Really?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form__item">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-btn">
    <p class="error-message error-message_main val-error">All the required fields have to be filled out.</p>
    <p class="error-message error-message_main_success val-success">Thanks. I'll contact you ASAP!</p>
  </div>
</form>


.error-message {
 display: none;
}

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".submit-btn").click(function(){

    var name = jQuery(".firstname").val();
    var email = jQuery(".email").val();
    var message = jQuery(".textarea").val();

    if(name === "" || email === "" || message === "") {
      jQuery(".val-error", ".error-message").css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/assets/php/send.php", 
        method:"POST",
        data:{name:firstname, email:email, message:comment},
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
          jQuery(".val-success").show(fast);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to prevent the default click event

Second you need a action variable to pass to the wordpress hook

3th you jquery selector for showing the errors is incorrect, the coma needs to be in the string

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".submit-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = jQuery(".firstname").val();
    var email = jQuery(".email").val();
    var message = jQuery(".textarea").val();

    if(name === "" || email === "" || message === "") {
      jQuery(".val-error, .error-message").show();//a little bit cleaner
    }
    else {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/assets/php/send.php", 
        method:"POST",
        data:{name:firstname, email:email, message:comment,action:'validate_form'},
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
          jQuery(".val-success").show(fast);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

for more information read the wp [documentation on ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot.

Comment: This action:"validate_form", is this a var I need to pass to the WP hook?

Answer (score 0):

Little changes required otherwise code is looking fine.Have a look

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submit-btn").click(function(){

    var name = $(".firstname").val();
    var email = $(".email").val();
    var message = $(".textarea").val();

    if(name === "" || email === "" || message === "") {
      $(".val-error", ".error-message").css("display", "block");
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        url:"/assets/php/send.php", 
        method:"POST",
        data:{name:name, email:email, message:message},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
              $("form").trigger("reset");
                $(".val-success").show(fast);  
            }                
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Pramod, thanks for prompt reply. I implemented that code to my WP theme, and still nothing works. Are you sure AJAX shouldn't be implemented to WP theme separately?

Comment: WP theme need some configuration to use inbuilt AJAX request. I would recommend to go through this [LINK](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/submitting-a-form-in-wordpress-using-ajax)

Comment: Thanks bud. Appreciate this!